# Javascript/Jquery Get only checked rows and export those rows to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, excel

I have a basic export function, but it exports the entire html table.

```
function Export() {
        var text= "<table><tr>";
        var range; var x= 0;
        tbl= document.getElementById('sum_table');


        for (x = 0; x< tbl.rows.length; x++) {

                text= text+ tbl.rows[x].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        }

        text= text+ "</table>";
        text= text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
        text= text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
        text= text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))     
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            doneSA = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "demo.xls");
        }
        else             
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(text));

        return (doneSA );
    }
```

I am now trying to change the for statement to ONLY include rows that have a checkbox column that is checked. Should i create a hidden table? How can i loop through the rows and check for a checked checkbox. I have tried multiple ways.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the "checked" property:

```
//inside for loop
$('.rowClassName').each(function(){
    if($('this').prop("checked"))
        text= text+ $(this).html() + "</tr>";
    }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: thanks that worked! i added a counter to include header. and used 'input[name=chkboxname]:checked'.each(function()){ generated html here }